# Access to Typedef struct pointer which is passed as double pointer to function. Access inside the function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, memory-management

I have difficulty in dealing with access to structure members inside a function, and structure instancies are double pointer arguments. I am using `strcpy` and `strcmp` and it seems, to me (I used debuger), to do the bad things.

First, I have created structure using `typedef`, instanciated it 2 times and allocated memory for one of  them.

Second, I have created function `loadVariablesToMemory` to which I am passing instanciated structure instancies as double pointers (2nd row - after //Functions comment).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//FUNCTIONS
int loadVariablesToMemory(const char* fileName, const char* fileAccessMode, varData **dynamicData, varData **tmp);



//DECLARATION
typedef unsigned short int UINT16;

typedef struct data {
    char varName[10];
    UINT16  value;
} varData;



int main(){

    //ALLOCATING MEMORY
    varData *dynamicData;
        dynamicData = (varData*)malloc(sizeof(varData));
   varData *tmp;
        tmp = NULL;

   int numOfVars = loadVariablesToMemory("u02v1_input_03.txt", "r", &dynamicData, &tmp);

   return 0;
}
```

Problem:
Inside the function `loadVariablesToMemory` I am trying to access allocated "variables" of structure instantiated and declared above, using:

```
.....
if(strcmp((*(dynamicalData+j-1))->varName, buffer) == 0){
.....etc.
strcpy((*(dynamicalData+numOfVars-1))->varName, buffer);
.....etc.
```

I run the debugger and all seems to work [also If I rewrite entire function outside into Main it works (with little changes with double pointers now single pointers)] but I got stuck in the rows where I use `strcpy();` and `strcmp()` functions and I dont know why and I am little bit desperate, because these two semms to be only two things that prevent me from creating a working function and I am getting desperate as I am dealing with this problem almost 10 hours without any real progress.

COMPLETE FUNCTION `loadVariablesToMemory`DECLARATION:

```
int loadVariablesToMemory(const char* fileName, const char* fileAccessMode, varData **dynamicalData, varData **tmpal) {


    FILE *fSource = fopen(fileName, fileAccessMode);

    char oneChar = '\0';
    char buffer[10];
        memset(buffer,'\0',10); //inicialization of buffer chars to \0

    int i = 0;
    int varOrNum = 0;
    int numOfVars = 0;

    bool match = false;

    while (!feof(fSource)) {
        oneChar = fgetc(fSource);           //Load letter in file
            if((oneChar == ' ') | (oneChar == '\n')) {
                i = 0;
                if((strcmp(buffer,"NOT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"AND") == 0)  || (strcmp(buffer,"OR") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"LSHIFT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"RSHIFT") == 0) || (strcmp(buffer,"->") == 0)) {
                    memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                }
                else{
                    varOrNum = atoi(buffer);    //returns (0) if varOrNum is variable (0)
                    if((varOrNum == 0) & (buffer[0] != '0'))
                    {                           //if varOrNum is a variable (0)

                        for(int j = 0; j<=numOfVars; j++) {     //control in memory for match of variable name
                            //HERE SEEMS NOT TO WORK - this is just random try if strcpy will work
                            //strcpy((*(dynamicalData+j-1))->varName, buffer);
                            //HERE SEEMS NOT TO WORK
                            if(strcmp((*(dynamicalData+j-1))->varName, buffer) == 0){
                                memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                                match = true;           //match found
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                                match = false;          //no match found
                        } //endForCycle

                       if(match == false){          //no match found
                            numOfVars++;            //number of variables for allocation
                            tmpal = (varData*)realloc((*dynamicalData), numOfVars * sizeof(varData));
                            if(!tmpal) {              //or equal to NULL
                                //printf("Could not resize/reallocate memory %i times \n", numOfVars);
                            }
                            else{
                                dynamicalData = tmpal;
                                strcpy((*(dynamicalData+numOfVars-1))->varName, buffer);
                                printf("%s \n", (*(dynamicalData+numOfVars-1))->varName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    varOrNum = 0;               //if varOrNum is a number (1)
                    memset(buffer,'\0',10);
                }
            }
            else{
                buffer[i] = oneChar;
                i++;
            }
    } //endWhileCycle (!feof(fSource))

fclose (fSource);
return  numOfVars;
}
```

INSIDE INPUT FILE: u02v1_input_03.txt

```
0 -> c
va OR dq -> v
NOT cx -> dr
kk RSHIFT 3 -> km
NOT cx -> dq
3 AND v -> fx
lf RSHIFT 2 -> lg
```

Can anybody be so nice and help me with that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Too much information missing. Please create [mcve].

Comment: post the complete (definition of)  `loadVariablesToMemory` function

Comment: I have edited the question and added the input file entry

Comment: Sidenote: a `typedef` does not create anything. It just generates an alias. You cannot create a custom type in C.

Comment: As you mentioned problem is in `if(strcmp((*(dynamicalData+j-1))->varName, buffer) == 0)`. If value of `j=0` and you were accessing/passing illegal memory to strcmp, verify for condition or your function flow

Comment: Doesnt work I just tried to give it to one place in function where I test these `strcpy`, `strcmp`, I got SIGSEGV. See pic: http://imgur.com/a/rs2vP

Comment: this line: `typedef unsigned short int UINT16;`  1) is a typedef, not a declaration 2) would be much better to use the macros in `stdint.h` (in this case: `uint16_t`  rather than hacking some new name

Comment: regarding these two lines: `char buffer[10];
        memset(buffer,'\0',10);`  Much better to write: `#define BUFFER_LEN 10   char buffer[ BUFFER_LEN ] = {'\0'};`  so it is an initialization statement rather than an assignment AND not using 'magic' numbers

Comment: the posted code is missing the necessary `#include` statements, so it does not compile.

Comment: NEVER use `while( !feof( fSource ) )`  the function `feof()` does not do what you think it does.  A much better statement would be: `while( (oneChar = fgetc(fSource) ) != EOF )`   of course, then the variable `oneChar` should be declared as: `int oneChar;`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) confine the width of the lines to a printable page (typically 80 characters)  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) avoid extraneous blank lines (like immediately after the function signature)  4) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{', unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level. 5) use appropriate horizontal spacing, like after a `,`, after a `;` and inside parens

Comment: this line: `if((varOrNum == 0) & (buffer[0] != '0'))` is performing a bit wise 'and' of the two variables.  suggest: `if((varOrNum == 0) && (buffer[0] != '0'))` Notice the operator `&&` between the two expressions, which performs a logical `AND` between the two expressions

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc): 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this line: `dynamicalData = tmpal;` is modifying the location on the local stack of the pointer to the `dynamicData`  What is should be modifying is the caller's instance of that variable, so the line should be: `*dynamicalData = tmpal;`  Note; the single dereference of the variable.

Comment: this kind of line: `strcpy((*(dynamicalData+numOfVars-1))->varName, buffer);`  will not work as planned due to the precedence of the operators in C,  suggest: `strcpy((*(*dynamicalData)+numOfVars-1))->varName, buffer);`  and even better would be: `strcpy( (*dynamicalData)[numOfVars-1])->varName, buffer);`

Comment: this line: `varOrNum = 0;               //if varOrNum is a number (1)` claims to be performing an `if()` statement, but all it is doing to performing an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if((varOrNum == 0) && (buffer[0] != '0')) {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j<numOfVars; j++) {
        if(strcmp(dynamicalData[j]->varName, buffer) == 0)
            break;
    }
    if(j>=numOfVars) {
        numOfVars++;            //number of variables for allocation
        tmpal = (varData*)realloc((*dynamicalData), numOfVars * sizeof(varData));
        if(!tmpal) {              //or equal to NULL
            //printf("Could not resize/reallocate memory %i times \n", numOfVars);
        }
        else{
            dynamicalData = tmpal;
            strcpy(dynamicalData[numOfVars-1]->varName, buffer);
            printf("%s \n", dynamicalData[numOfVars-1]->varName);
        }
    }
}
varOrNum = 0;               //if varOrNum is a number (1)
memset(buffer,'\0',10);
```

In the 1st line you missed a &.
In the 1st loop (j==0) you do a strcmp  `dynamicalData+j-1` which means `dynamicalData[-1]`

Comment: OK. SO problem seems to be invalid memory address in for loop: `for(int j = 0; j<=numOfVars; j++)` I got condition: `if(strcmp((*(dynamicalData+j-1))->varName, buffer) == 0)` I am accessing `[-1]` memory address for `j=0` what is to be illegal